# Convert column to datetime format, in a leap year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm new to Python and programming in general, so I wasn't able to figure out the following: I have a dataframe named ozon, for which column 1 is the time stamp in mm-dd format. Now I want to change that column to a datetime format using the following code:

```
ozon[1] = pd.to_datetime(ozon[1], format='%m-%d')
```

Now this is giving me the following error: ValueError: day is out of range for month.
I think it has to do with the fact that it's a leap year, so it doesn't recognize February 29 as a valid date. How can I overcome this error? And could I also add a year to the timestamp (2020)?
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to store a year with your month&day date - you just found the reason why ;-) Now to fix this, assuming col at index 1 is of dtype string, you should simply be able to prepend the year as a string: `pd.to_datetime('2020-'+ozon[1], format='%Y-%m-%d')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add year to column and also to `format`:

```
ozon[1] = pd.to_datetime(ozon[1] + '-2000', format='%m-%d-%Y')
```

If still not working because some values are not valid add `errors='coerce'` parameter:

```
ozon[1] = pd.to_datetime(ozon[1] + '-2000', format='%m-%d-%Y', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, what if I dont wanna keep the year value? I need to do a comparison bar chart with three days as a unit X-axis. To satisfy the format of X-axis, year value is abandoned. Then I met this trouble, is there a way to convert February, 29th to pd.DateTime type without adding year value?